# ScriptEditor application signed but not accepted by Gatekeeper

Tags: applescript, developer-program

I created a small AppleScript app to launch a webservice locally using the built-in PHP webserver. It's an interface to generate XML configurations.

Since macOS Sierra those apps are moved to the AppTranslocation directory if they are not signed. I just became an Apple Developer to be able to export the script from **Script Editor.app** as an app, signed with my Application Developer ID. Yet, when I push everything to Github and download the package as a zip file, the signed app is still executed from the AppTranslocation directory. What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider distributing your application within a [code signed disk image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824815/how-to-add-codesigning-to-dmg-file-in-mac/38431237), `dmg`, file. The contents of a code signed disk image are not subject to “Gatekeeper Path Randomization” (GPR).

See [How do I create a nice-looking DMG for Mac OS X using command-line tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882/how-do-i-create-a-nice-looking-dmg-for-mac-os-x-using-command-line-tools?rq=1) for a guide to creating a disk image.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'll give that a shot and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I managed to make it work by codesigning the app generated by **Script Maker.app** and codesigning the dmg as well. The final command I used to generate the dmg is `hdiutil create -size 35m -srcfolder /path/to/source/dir -fs HFS+ -volname AppName /path/to/final.dmg`.